# Ruby error could not find the generator integration_test_static_pages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, integration-testing

i am following the tutorails on net for ruby on rails  http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/static-pages#sec-static_pages

And when i run the command `rails generate integration_test_static_pages` and i got the error
 **Could not find the generator integration_test_static_pages**  .I have update the bundle using `bundle update` and also updated all the dependencies using `bundle install` but  why this error is raising?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry i was entering the wrong command, the actuall command is `rails generate integration_test static_pages`.

Resolved one!! hurrah.